# Security consideration on saving http_* variables to database

Tags: php, ruby, session-cookies

As web developer, is it dangerous to store client's cookie (HTTP_COOKIE) and any other HTTP_* variables to database?

example for the cookie content:

> PHPSESSID=49g8iequfgjf5h9rjne88nqfs1; rack.session=BAh7CUkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFVEkiRTUyYzBhZTYyYmY2ZjI5OWVmZjM3%0ANzk3NTA5MWQ1OTVjNTBkYjIzZDIwZmJlMzc2MGI5ODllYzU0NDQyMjkxMDQG%0AOwBGSSINdHJhY2tpbmcGOwBGewhJIhRIVFRQX1VTRVJfQUdFTlQGOwBUSSIt%0AMGNkYzFiOWRVlKrM2E4MWM0MTdmMWFkNDcwMGQxODBjM2Q4N2NhZQY7AEZJ%0AIhlIVFRQX0FDQ0VQVF9FTkNPRElORwY7AFRJIi1lZDJiM2NhOTBhNGU3MjM0%0AMDIzNjdhMWQxN2M4YjI4MzkyODQyMzk4BjsARkkiGUhUVFBfQUNDRVBUX0xB%0ATkdVQUdFBjsAVEkibTVuZWFlOTcxNDkyOTM4YzJkY8923mIxZGRjOGQ3ZWMz%0AMTk2MDM3ZGEGOwBGSSIKcHJvZGkGOwBGWwZ7BzoHaWRpEzoJbmFtZUkiCEhD%0ASQY7AFRJIgljc3JmBjsARkkiRTFmN2M4NzVjZDQ2ZWMwNWM2YmM2MjU2MWMw%0AZWI2NzU1Y2Y1NTQ2OWY1NmIyNmM3NGNjMWZhNjhhMjg3NDVhNTQGOwBG%0A\n

Answer (score 1):

Anything you get from a cookie or from the HTTP request should be treated as user input and not trusted. If you're storing in the database, use a Prepared Statement and avoid concatenating the variables into the SQL.

In PHP, the use of [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) is preferred to reading the raw cookie to get the session ID. If the session name is different from the default, then the cookie will not be named `PHPSESSID`.

Comment: this not what i meant ^^ but thanks, what i meant is would it be less secure than not saving HTTP_* to database?

Comment: The security lies with what operations you do on the data rather than the content itself. So if you use a Prepared Statement then it's no less secure than a database without those variables. If you output the data into HTML then you have other considerations such as preventing XSS.